# Map Reduce with mongoDB and Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce, morphia

I am running map reduce in mongoDB with morphia, this is my java code

```
String map = "function() { emit(this.id,this.cal.charge)}";
String reduce = "function(k, v) {var i, sum = 0;for (i in v) {sum += v[i];}return sum;}";

MapreduceResults<Results> mrRes = ds.mapReduce(MapreduceType.MERGE,ds.createQuery(MyTable.class).field("id").equal(5),map,reduce,null,null,Re.class);
```

This work fine and put results to 'Re' collection, but how can i get result as objects or list without inserting to a new Collection ?

Thanks

Comment: see inline option to mapReduce command for output parameter.  Also this looks like a very simple calculation - you might consider the aggregation framework which is much faster and will return the results back as a single document.

Comment: Instead of MapreduceType.MERGE use MapreduceType.INLINE.

Comment: @cubbuk : its not working with MapreduceType.INLINE, it gave 'Inline map/reduce is not supported' error.

Comment: which version of morphia you are using?

Comment: seems like morphia didn't implement inline functionality yet, check out the source code, it is marked as todo for inline type: http://code.google.com/p/morphia/source/browse/trunk/morphia/src/main/java/com/google/code/morphia/DatastoreImpl.java?r=1743

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't commented this because it violates the length limit.

If it is not going to be too much of a fuss, you can do it by using java driver directly without using the morphia interface. just get the mongo object from morphia datastore and use java driver's map reduce command; it is something like this:

```
DBObject queryObject = new BasicDBObject("id", 5);
DBCollection collection = ds.getCollection(MyTable.class);

MapReduceCommand mrc = new MapReduceCommand(collection, // collection to do map-reduce on
                                            map, // map function
                                            reduce, // reduce function
                                            null, // output collection for the result
                                            MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, // output result type
                                            queryObject); // query to use in map reduce function
```

btw morphia has a newer version in github https://github.com/jmkgreen/morphia maybe you wanna check that out too. I saw that the newer version also don't support inline operation on map-reduce.